# How to distribute values into group in python

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning

I have a dataset of actions doing over time, an attribute 'Hour' ( contains values from 0 ->23 ). Now I want to create another attribute, say 'PartOfDay', which group 24 hours into 4 parts. For tuples have 'Hour' value of 0 to 5, then the 'PartOfDay' value should be 1; if 'Hour' value in [6,11], then the 'PartOfDay' value should be 2;...How can I do?

The codes would do this:

```
train['PartOfDay']=1
train.loc[(train.Hour>=6) & (train.hour<=11),'PartOfDay']=2
train.loc[(train.Hour>=12) & (train.hour<=17),'PartOfDay']=3
train.loc[(train.Hour>=18) & (train.hour<=23),'PartOfDay']=4
```

but it seems not so beautiful, I would like to know a more decent one if possible

Thank you for all your supports!!

Comment: can you give us some semi-code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is not clear what train.loc represents, a general approach to your problem is to use modulus function to set the RHS:

```
 1 + int(train.Hour / 6)
```